# How to handle spring security InternalAuthenticationServiceException thrown in Spring ProviderManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot

ProviderManager is throwing InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class while retrieving users in DaoAuthenticationProvider.class,

```
 loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
```

I want to handle this exception and return my custom response to the client.

I don't want to handle this by writing custom ProviderManager.

For all other OAuth exceptions  i am able to handle the exceptions using  Custom WebResponseExceptionTranslator.

But I am unable to catch security exceptions like InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class.

I don't have option to use ErrorController with the /error path, it is breaking other flows.

Comment: What is the Framework you are using for Web? Spring Controllers or Jersey?

Comment: @shazin I am using Spring boot and spring security 2.0.8

Comment: am facing this issue too.. what was the solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a class which is annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` and have a `@ExceptionHandler(value=InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class)`.

Ex:-

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleInternalAuthenticationServiceException(InternalAuthenticationServiceException e) {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = new ResponseEntity<String>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return response;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't have controllers and using `@EnableAuthorizationServer` then you need to extend from `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and override `configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)` as below. You can use `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.exceptionTranslator` to handle your `InternalAuthenticationServiceException`.

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints
                // other endpoints
                .exceptionTranslator(e -> {
                    if (e instanceof InternalAuthenticationServiceException) {
                        InternalAuthenticationServiceException internalAuthenticationServiceException = (InternalAuthenticationServiceException) e;

                        // return a ResponseEntity or throw a custom Exception.
                    } 
                });
    }
```

Comment: ControllerAdvice is not getting called when the exception thrown at security. I am using @EnableAuthorizationServer so i don't have any explicit controller in my service.

Comment: The method exceptionTranslator(WebResponseExceptionTranslator<OAuth2Exception>) in the type AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> e) -> {})

Comment: Even after implementing an exception handler for InternalAuthenticationServiceException in a class (annotated with Controller Advice), the exception is not getting caught and application is continuing to throw Internal Server error along with the base exception. Is there a possibility of handler getting bypassed here?

Answer (score 3):

First you need to implements your own **AuthenticationEntryPoint** the name is not really autoexplicative...

For example if you need to return always status code 200 (only for learning purpose, please don´t do it in real world...)

```
@Component("myOwnAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public class MyOwnAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, "Unauthorized");
    }
```

Then in your WebSecurityConfig you need to set it as your authentication exception handler entry point.

```
...

public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    ...

    @Autowired
    MyOwnAuthenticationEntryPoint myOwnAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(myOwnAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    ...
    }
```

Thats all. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that problem by override unsuccessfulAuthentication method in my filter and send an error response to the client with the desired HTTP status code. In my case, I also created my custom exception (RecordNotFoundException) that is thrown from my service.

```
@Override
protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (failed.getCause() instanceof RecordNotFoundException) {
        response.sendError((HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND), failed.getMessage());
    }
}
```