# How do I make Spring Security return a 500 instead of a 403 when a InternalAuthenticationServiceException is thrown

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security to handle auth on my RESTful-ish webservice.

The goal is to create a `/login` endpoint for which the user provides a username/password and which returns a JWT. I'm loosely following this guide: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

I've got the happy-path working; when a user provides a valid user/pass, a valid JWT is returned to them.

The problem is my error case. If my `UserService.loadUserByUsername` method (which is called by Spring Security in order to validate the user/pass) throws an IOException, I want Spring to return a 500 error. Instead, Spring returns a 403. I stepped through the internal Spring classes a bit, and they clearly differentiate between a `AuthenticationException` (which is thrown when auth fails) and a `InternalAuthenticationServiceException` (which is thrown when auth is unable to be completed due to an internal error). I want a 500 error returned when an `InternalAuthenticationServiceException` is encountered. How to I configure Spring to do this? Will I need to implement my own AuthenticationFailureHandler?

Comment: does this answer your question? [how-to-handle-spring-security-internalauthenticationserviceexception-thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39789408/how-to-handle-spring-security-internalauthenticationserviceexception-thrown-in-s)

Comment: i do not recommend that tutorial, it is old, its using an outdated spring security, and custom authentication is always a bad idea. You should learn the standard ways of basic authentication, and using jwts with oauth2.

Comment: Crud, I had thought that something provided on Auth0's site would be the standard. I'll try to find a different guide to follow.

Comment: You need to configure a custom `AuthenticationEntryPoint` to handle `AuthenticationException`, which `InternalAuthenticationServiceException` indirectly extends from. See the reference for details on how the authentication flow works https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Thomas Andolf said, it might have been best for me to simply implement an OAuth2 flow instead of a custom authentication solution. However, if you want to implement a custom authentication solution, and if you want to return specific HTTP error codes for specific errors, then you can write a custom AuthenticationFailureHandler to accomplish this. I'm not sure if this is a good solution, but it is a solution. Something like this:

```
class CustomAuthenticationFilter(authManager: AuthenticationManager) : AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter(AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST")) {

    init{
        this.authenticationManager = authManager;
        this.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
        this.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler())
    }

    @Throws(AuthenticationException::class, PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException::class)
    override fun attemptAuthentication(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse): Authentication {

        // insert code to parse the request into a username and password

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        username,
                        password,
                        ArrayList())
        )
    }
}

class CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler: AuthenticationSuccessHandler{
    override fun onAuthenticationSuccess(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, authentication: Authentication?) {

        // these next three lines simply verify that none of the inputs are null; this is Kotlin syntax.
        request!!
        response!!
        authentication!!

        val username = (authentication.principal as User).getUsername();
        val expiration = Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_DURATION_MILLIS)

        // insert code to create a JWT and write it to the response
        // no need to return anything
    }
}

class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler : AuthenticationFailureHandler{
    override fun onAuthenticationFailure(request: HttpServletRequest?, response: HttpServletResponse?, exception: AuthenticationException?) {

        // these next two lines simply verify that none of the inputs are null; this is Kotlin syntax.
        request!!
        response!!

        when (exception) {
            is PreAuthenticatedCredentialsNotFoundException -> {
                response.status = 400;
            }
            is AuthenticationServiceException -> {
                response.status = 500;
            }
            else -> {
                response.status = 401;
                // consider adding a WWW-Authenticate header as well
            }
        }
    }
}
```